# Ubuntu Tomcat showing different user and group for war and extracted context

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am deploying a war file in Amazon EC2 I am logged in as user ubuntu and deploying the war file as same user. After deploying the war I am starting the tomcat "service tomcat7 start" from ROOT. Now the extracted contextroot is showing the user and group as tomcat7.

Can any body help me what can fix this?

I want to fix this because I want to access /home/ubuntu but as the contextroot is showing user tomcat7 I am getting Permission error when trying to write a file under /home/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The solution I think for this is allow other user as read only access to folder `/home/ubuntu`

example:

```
   #Allow other User a Read-Only access to /home/ubuntu recursively
   chmod -R o+r /home/ubuntu
```

OR If you have access `/etc/init.d/tomcat`, look for the `TOMCAT_USER` and change it to your preferred `ubuntu user name`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want the write access also under this folder.

Comment: #Command to allow Read and Write recursively
`chmod -R o+rw /home/ubuntu`

Comment: is it equivalent to 777 ?

Comment: `777` is for everyone to have access read, write, execute to that folder. The `777` is equivalent of `a+rwx`

Comment: Thanks. I did the tomcat change.  TOMCAT7_USER=ubuntu
TOMCAT7_GROUP=ubuntu from tomcat7
But still after restart of tomcat the contextroot is showing tomcat7

Comment: check if you can find `/etc/default/tomcat7` file and try changing the user settings to `TOMCAT7_USER=ubuntu` and `TOMCAT7_GROUP=ubuntu`

Comment: Yes. I did that only. But still the same